# Prolog - understanding recursive predicate returning list

Tags: recursion, prolog

I am very new to Prolog and wondering if I could get some help in better understanding the below code. I understand the code relating to 'divides' and 'find_num', but I am having difficulty with wrapping my head around what is happening with 'check_list'. Any help in furthering my understanding would be greatly appreciated.

```
 divides(X, Y) :-
     X mod Y =:= 0.

 find_num(X, Y, Lout) :-
      findall(N, between(1, X, N), Lin),
      check_list(Lin, Y, Lout).

 check_list([], _, []).

 check_list([H | Tin], Y, [H | Tout]) :-
   divides(H, Y),
   check_list(Tin, Y, Tout).

 check_list([H | Tin], Y, Lout) :-
   \+ divides(H, Y),
   check_list(Tin, Y, Lout).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at a simpler predicate:

```
copy_list([],[]).
copy_list([H|Tin],[H|Tout]) :- copy_list(Tin,Tout).
```

If you pass in two identical lists then this predicate will succeed if they are equal. If you pass one list and one variable, either way around, then this will copy the list.

It's convention to put inputs on the left and outputs on the right.

Let's look at this query:

```
?- copy_list([1,2,3],Xs).
```

Internally Prolog (in my case SWI) replaces the variable `Xs` with an internal name, so the first call is `copy_list([1, 2, 3], _52812)`. Prolog looks for a predicate match and finds `copy_list([H|Tin],[H|Tout])`. It then unifies and gets `copy_list([1|2,3],[1|_55684])`. It then tries to prove the body.

Its second call is `copy_list([2,3],_55684)`. Prolog looks for a predicate match and finds `copy_list([H|Tin],[H|Tout])`. It then unifies and gets `copy_list([2|3],[2|_69116])`. It then tries to prove the body.

Its third call is `copy_list([3],_69116)`. Prolog looks for a predicate match and finds `copy_list([H|Tin],[H|Tout])`. It then unifies and gets `copy_list([3|[]],[3|_69734])`. It then tries to prove the body.

On its forth call the empty list predicate `copy_list([],[]).` now matches. So it begins to unwind the recursion. It unifies `_69734` with the empty list. It unifies `_69116` with `[3]`, and then `_55684` with `[2,3]` and finally `_52812` with `[1,2,3]` and it declares success. The program is true.

In a nutshell, it does this:

```
copy_list([1, 2, 3], _52812)
copy_list([2, 3], _55684)
copy_list([3], _69116)
copy_list([], _69734)
copy_list([], [])
copy_list([3], [3])
copy_list([2, 3], [2, 3])
copy_list([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])
```